# CSS3 - Speech Bubble

Tags: html, css, speech

I wish to create a speech bubble box like this:

[image: Bubble]

I am wondering on how to make a "comment box" like this inside a **td** table element.
How can I obtain this with just CSS?

I have this HTML markup:

```
            <table class="forum" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="userinfo">User Info</td>
                    <td class="text">
                    Speech Buble shoudl be here with text inside.

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Answer (score 0):

There are some speech bubble generators are available now

Just try this one 
http://www.ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/

might be useful for quick result